Shopware 6 - StorefrontExtension - registerThemeServiceAliases - $theme is null - v6.5.8.13
after I switched my deployment via deployer 7.0, I've got a new error in the console:
cd /html/shop_deployer/releases/26/
php bin/console

Output:
Warning: Undefined array key "theme" in /html/shop_deployer/releases/26/vendor/shopware/storefront/DependencyInjection/StorefrontExtension.php on line 27

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Shopware\Storefront\DependencyInjection\StorefrontExtension::registerThemeServiceAliases(): Argument #1 ($theme) must be of type array, null given, called in /html/shop_deployer/releases/26/vendor/shopware/storefront/DependencyInjection/StorefrontExtension.php on line 27 and defined in /html/shop_deployer/releases/26/vendor/sh>
Stack trace:
#0 /html/shop_deployer/releases/26/vendor/shopware/storefront/DependencyInjection/StorefrontExtension.php(27): Shopware\Storefront\DependencyInjection\StorefrontExtension->registerThemeServiceAliases(NULL, Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\MergeExtensionConfigurationContainerBuilder))
#1 /html/shop_deployer/releases/26/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Compiler/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php(78): Shopware\Storefront\DependencyInjection\StorefrontExtension->load(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\MergeExtensionConfigurationContainerBuilder))
#2 /html/shop_deployer/releases/26/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/DependencyInjection/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php(42): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder))
#3 /html/shop_deployer/releases/26/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Compiler/Compiler.php(80): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder))
#4 /html/shop_deployer/releases/26/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php(767): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder))
#5 /html/shop_deployer/releases/26/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(506): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile()
#6 /html/shop_deployer/releases/26/vendor/shopware/core/Kernel.php(193): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer()
#7 /html/shop_deployer/releases/26/bin/console(53): Shopware\Core\Kernel->boot()
#8 /html/shop_deployer/releases/26/vendor/autoload_runtime.php(24): {closure}(Array)
#9 /html/shop_deployer/releases/26/bin/console(16): require_once('...')
#10 {main}
  thrown in /html/shop_deployer/releases/26/vendor/shopware/storefront/DependencyInjection/StorefrontExtension.php on line 41

What I have done:

upgraded PHP 8.1 to 8.3
switched the "build-js" scripts from the live-Server to gitlab
added a new Plugin/Theme

Locally everything works fine, but the production server is missing something, I can't see.
I added a little output in the class MergeExtensionConfigurationPass:

class MergeExtensionConfigurationPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        // ...

        foreach ($container->getExtensions() as $name => $extension) {
echo "name:".$name."\n";
            if (!$config = $container->getExtensionConfig($name)) {
                // this extension was not called
                continue;
            }
var_dump($config);echo "\n";

Output of the last $config:
name:storefront
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}

What is missing? Can anyone help, please?
Edit: I think I need to clear the cache. But without the faulty bin/console, I just can't.
The folder var/cache/prod_* is missing.

I've got the solution.
In the production system the folder vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/config/packages was non existant.
I'm using deployer similar to the documentation of Shopware. Like in the documentation, I've set the shared_dirs:
set('shared_dirs', [
    'config/packages', // this is faulty. This has to be removed
    'config/jwt',
    // ...
]);

And there it is. If you set a folder in shared_dirs, every folder like this will be excluded. I removed the folder and added the necessary file in here:
set('shared_files', [
    'config/packages/z-shopware.yaml',
    // ...
]);

Problem solved. :)
